# Почему возникает разрыв в блоках flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

В примере внизу возникает разрыв ввиде черного цвета, назначенного тегу HTML. При этом контейнеру flexbox Body был назначен белый цвет и фон в этом месте должен быть белым. Почему возникает этот разрыв между основным блоком и футером? Как починить?

[Пример разметки

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    html {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: white;
        }

            .header {
                background-color: #3E464F;
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 50px;
                flex: 0 0 auto;
            }

                .h-limiter {
                    width: 1100px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }

                    .logo {
                        height: 100%;
                        width: 171px;
                        background-color: #3A4047;
                    }

                    .nav {

                    }

                    .user-menu {
                        height: 100%;
                        width: 52px;
                        background-color: #3A4047;
                    }
        
        .subheader {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            // background-color: pink;
            background-image: url(/source/images/bg.png);
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            display: flex;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
            
            .s-limiter {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width: 1100px;
                margin: 0 auto;

            }
        .subnav {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 59px;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            display: flex;

        }
            .sn-limiter {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width: 1100px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                align-self: center;
            }

        .main {
            background-color: white;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            align-self: stretch;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex: 1 0 auto;


        }

            .m-limiter {
                height: 600px;
                width: 1100px;
                background-color: whitesmoke;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                align-self: stretch;
    
            }

        .footer {
            background-color: #3E464F;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-top: 150px;

        }

            .f-limiter {
                height: 250px;
                width: 1100px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                box-sizing: border-box;

            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="h-limiter">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="nav"></div>
            <div class="user-menu"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="subheader"><div class="s-limiter"></div></section>
    <section class="subnav"><div class="sn-limiter"><p>team > blog</p></div></section>
    <main class="main"><div class="m-limiter"></div></main>
    <footer class="footer"><div class="f-limiter"></div></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

убрать height: 100% у html, body